# LibGDX Do Something One Time During Update Method

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm a bit new to Java and LibGDX, and I'm working on a point based game. A problem I'm facing is that the update method constantly runs something that I want to run on a timely manner. In my update method, I have the code to increment the score if a point is earned, and to make a lose state come up when the player lost. Without going into much detail, here's the pseudo code I have:

```
 protected void update(float dt){

    for(Thing x : a list) {

        x.update(dt);

        //continue
        if (you complete the objective of the game) {
            score++;
            //do other stuff
        }


        //lost
        if (you fail to complete the objective){
            make lose state come up
        }
     }

//I want something like this to run:
if(score >=0 && score <=10){
  do something ONCE(ie. print to console once)
}
if(score >= 11 && score <=15){
  do something once
}
if(ect...){
  do something else once
}
.
.
.
```

The problem here is that, if the IF condition is met, I notice the IF block gets executed multiple times very quickly(ie. printing to the console a lot). I have enclosed the details of the code that relies on the score in a separate class, I just want to be able to call the method from this update method and have it run once depending on the score conditions (ie. run it again if the score satisfies another IF statement)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I solved it by using following method. In Libgdx the update method runs in 1/60 second. That is the reason the method is rendering continously and the if condition will be executing various times.
To solve this problem, just declare an integer variable, say `count`, in your `create` method.

```
public static int count;
public static void create()
{
    count =0;
    // do other stuffs
}
protected void update(float dt){
    // just increment this count value in your update method
    for(Thing x : a list) {
        count++
        x.update(dt);
        //continue
        if (you complete the objective of the game) {
            score++;
            //do other stuff
        }
        //lost
        if (you fail to complete the objective){
            make lose state come up
        }
    }
    // and make a small condition to run the if condition only once by using  the declared variable "count".
    if(count%60==0){
        // here the condition only executes when the count%60==0.that is only once in 1/60 frames.
        if(score >=0 && score <=10){
        }
        if(score >= 11 && score <=15){
        }
        if(ect...){
        }
    }
```

.
.
. This is how I solved the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `update()` method is called every frame, multiple times very quickly(usually 60 times per second) in an infinite loop. This is not only specific in libGDX, but in any game engine. And when some condition of your `if` block evaluates to `true`, that `if` block is executed every frame until that condition becomes `false` again. But you want to execute the block only once after the condition changed.

Just declare a variable named `isLastScoreUnder10` or whatever, and update it after the `if` block. Like this:

```
private boolean isLastScoreUnder10 = false;

protected void update(float dt){

    if(!isLastScoreUnder10 && score >=0 && score <=10){
        isLastScoreUnder10 = true;

        // ..do something

    } else {
        isLastScoreUnder10 = false;
    }
}
```